# Can I make an hybrid app autoplay video when installed on iOS or Android?

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app

I am working on a video platform where we have a webapp and have the requirement for having an app downloadable from the stores - for which we are using a hybrid app approach by wrapping the webapp using IONIC CLI.

Autoplay is something most browsers do not support i.e. a user click must be registered before autplaying video.

Is it possible for a hybrid app to access native video player so that the video player can autoplay videos? How can I solve this issue to bypass autoplay restrictions when the app is installed as a hybrid app?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the video autoplay by muting the video on `ionic`.

```
    <video inViewport 
           playsinline loop
           [muted]="'muted'" preload="auto" muted="muted" 
           id="video1" class="video-media">
       <source src="{{chosenVideoHolder}}" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

TS file to unmute when user click on the video:

```
public changeVideoAudio(id: string) {
    let vid: any = document.getElementById('video1');
    vid.muted = !vid.muted;
}
```